# How to use grouping and aggregation in NetSuite saved search?

Tags: netsuite

I want to create a search that filters the records like Display the name of every customer and Sum of amount of orders placed by that customer in the last thirty days. I want to apply the search on sales orders.

Answer (score 0):

In the results  Tabs   try  this:
[image: Group by]